# Isn't there a way to "mouse over" a condition in an "if" statement to see true or false in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

While debugging, isn't there a way to "mouse over" a condition in an "if" statement to see if it evaluates to true or false in VS2010? I could have sworn there was, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Mouse-over the operator.  For `if(a || b)`, simply mouse-over the `||`.

You can even break down complex expressions.  For `if(a || !(b is string))` you can mouse-over the `!(` portion to see what the result of the negation is.

Be sure you know your order of operations, though.  For `if(a || b && c)`, the `||` will give you the final result, where the `&&` will give you the result of only the `b && c` portion.

Comment: I guess my problem was with the type of statement I was using...    if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\TRAM\TM"))

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the condition and type Ctrl-Alt-Q (quick watch).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you select/highlight the expression, then hover over the selected text, it will show you the evaluation of whatever is selected.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can set your condition value to a bool variable and during debugging you can see it's value... Fore example:

```
bool condition = a > b;
if (condition)
{
   // Do some stuff
}
```

And while debugging "mouse over" `condition`.